# Exported JAR Can't Access Packaged Libraries

Tags: java, export, libraries

I am attempting to export my project as a JAR file. It uses a few external libraries. Here's my package structure in Eclipse:

[image: Package Structure]

When I export the project as a JAR, the libraries export. However, when I run the program, I get a ClassNotFoundException because one of my classes is trying to access a library.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either export your JAR as `runnable JAR` and select the option of `Copy required libraries next to generated JAR`.

OR

You can also refer your external libraries using command :

`java -Djava.ext.dirs=lib -jar yourJAR.jar`

Comment: I need the program to be 100% self-contained (just one file to send to people).

Comment: But if you need it to be just one big runnable JAR file then you should go with File > Export > Runnable JAR File and make sure the "Extract required libraries into generated JAR" is selected.

Comment: Thanks @Cebence for the comment. PogoStick : You can do as per above comment, that will give you a self contained JAR.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a manifest with something like this:

```
Class-Path: lib/sphinx4.jar lib/jl1.0.1.jar lib/WS.....
```

More information [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)